# How do I get notified when response received form tcp/ip channel

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcp

I have to send and receive message synchronously through TCP/IP. I have used an example from this link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb5kfec7.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1 
However I have forced to introduce Sleep (mentioned below) between send and receive otherwise I get empty message.

```
// Send the data through the socket.
int bytesSent = sender.Send(msg);

Thread.sleep(1000) // But, I only wanted to be in sleep until response received. 

// Receive the response from the remote device.
int bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);
```

Please suggest how can I only wait until response received. 
Thanks,

Comment: Asynchoronous command instead of synchronous? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a.aspx

Comment: The example you linked to is for synchronous communication.  If you follow the example exactly, `Receive` should block until it gets a return value.  The header for the demo says it directly: "The client is built with a synchronous socket, so execution of the client application is suspended until the server returns a response."  The documentation for Socket.Receive agrees - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s4y8aff.aspx  You'll have to show your specific code.

Comment: I have to make a synchronous call.  I can't see any bytes updated without sleep statement.

Comment: How do you expect to Receive an object if it takes time to create it ? my first guess is you trying to receive something that is not ready yet.

Comment: BTW this is exactly what scott is saying, Since your call is synchronous, you must block until result is ready, and only then call Receive.

Comment: @ilansch - Please have a quick look at Scott comment above.

Comment: ..and then get rid of the sleep() call and fix your real bug, whatever that is.

Comment: @ilansch Receive will block, so I don't want block using Sleep.. that is the problem. Anyway I will keep try for a solution.

Comment: @Chris_web but receive will only block until the server sends a reply, and it will block exactly as long as it takes for the server to send the reply.  If you're doing synchronous communication, that's exactly what you want.  (Synchronous means "receive will wait until the other side says something".  Your other choice is asynchronous, which means "you go on and do other things, and receive an event when the other side says something, and then deal with it.")

Comment: Can you correct me if I am wrong, Server is independent of how client send messages(sync/Async)?

Comment: @ScottMermelstein - I totally agree with you. Could be a bug in my code that not letting Receive to suspend until it receives response.

Comment: @Chris_web Heh.  Maybe that's why I said, "You'll have to show your specific code"?  ;-)  Either you've set the socket to no longer be synchronous, or your server returns an empty value the first time.  We can help you with either of those if you post more code...

Comment: @Chris_web Sorry, I just noticed your "Can you correct me..." comment.  Yes, the server is independent from the client.  It runs as a separate process, and could be on an entirely different computer.  It doesn't know about the client, other than knowing that the client has opened a connection to it.  Whether the client is asynchronous or synchronous, the connection will remain between the client and the server.  (But if the server has a bug, it may return an empty response the first time a connection - whether sync or async - is made.)

Comment: @ScottMermelstein - You are correct again, its a problem with differ way sending packets by server. I am updating answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, thank you all for your initiation and inputs to resolve this issue.

Yes, this issue appeared due to mis-understanding of communication between client and server. Server is sending response message in multiple packets - it send data in the order of header, message and tail packet at the end. so my client's - Receive method assumes that it has received full message as soon as header received first and tried de-serialize to an object and failed

When I had given a sleep statement as part of troubleshooting, it was working because it receives full message within this time.

Now, as part of resolution, I have updated Server application to buffer full message and write to network at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the following:

- does the server respond to all your requests?
- is your request synchronous?
- is the timeout of the request too small?

Anyway, you need to wake up, do not sleep anymore.

Comment: Please refer question again, all details available. I am happy to update question if I miss anything. Thanks

Comment: I cannot refer to your question, because you have only a snippet of your code in there. We do not know, for instance what happens with sender before the snippet in your question.